# Accessing string info outside public LocationResult

Tags: android

i have a script as follows getting the url from the LocationResult to use in the httppost

```
public class List extends ListActivity {

    int ct_id;
    String[] ct_number = null;
    String[] ct_address = null;
    String[] ct_phone = null;
    String[] ct_fax = null;
    String[] ct_email = null;
    String[] ct_city = null;
    String[] ct_province = null;
    String[] ct_country = null;
    String[] ct_pcode = null;
    String[] ct_lat = null;
    String[] ct_long = null;
    String[] ct_distance = null;
    String[] ct_show = null;
    String[] ct_listinfo = null;

    MyLocation myLocation = new MyLocation();

    public void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
        super.onCreate(bundle);
        setContentView(R.layout.timslist);
        findCurrentLocation();

        //check for key to remove ads
        if(isKeyInstalled(this) == false){

            //AdMob Banner
            LinearLayout parent = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.adveiw);
            AdView ad = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, "XXXXXXXXXXXXXX");
            parent.addView(ad);
            AdRequest r = new AdRequest();
            //r.setTesting(true);
            r.setTesting(false);
            ad.loadAd(r);
        }

        if(isKeyInstalled(this) == true){

        }

        String result = null;
        InputStream is = null;
        StringBuilder sb = null;
        //http post
        try{
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("" + infourl + "");
            //httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            is = entity.getContent();
        }catch(Exception e){
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection"+e.toString());
        }
        //convert response to string
        try{
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);
            sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.append(reader.readLine() + "\n");
            String line="0";
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            result=sb.toString();
        }catch(Exception e){
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result"+e.toString());
        }
        //paring data
        JSONArray jArray;
        try{
            jArray = new JSONArray(result);
            JSONObject json_data=null;
            ct_number=new String[jArray.length()];
            ct_address=new String[jArray.length()];
            ct_phone=new String[jArray.length()];
            ct_fax=new String[jArray.length()];
            ct_email=new String[jArray.length()];
            ct_city=new String[jArray.length()];
            ct_province=new String[jArray.length()];
            ct_country=new String[jArray.length()];
            ct_pcode=new String[jArray.length()];
            ct_lat=new String[jArray.length()];
            ct_long=new String[jArray.length()];
            ct_distance=new String[jArray.length()];
            ct_listinfo=new String[jArray.length()];
            for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){
                json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                ct_id=json_data.getInt("location_id");
                ct_number[i]=json_data.getString("store_number");
                ct_address[i]=json_data.getString("store_address");
                ct_phone[i]=json_data.getString("store_phone");
                ct_fax[i]=json_data.getString("store_fax");
                ct_email[i]=json_data.getString("store_email");
                ct_city[i]=json_data.getString("store_city");
                ct_province[i]=json_data.getString("store_province");
                ct_country[i]=json_data.getString("store_country");
                ct_pcode[i]=json_data.getString("store_pcode");
                ct_lat[i]=json_data.getString("store_lat");
                ct_long[i]=json_data.getString("store_long");
                ct_distance[i]=json_data.getString("store_distance");
                ct_listinfo[i] = new String (ct_address[i] + "\n" + ct_city[i] + ", " + ct_province[i] + " - " + ct_distance[i] + " Km Away");
            }
        }
        catch(JSONException e1){
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No Addresses Found" ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } catch (ParseException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.listview,ct_listinfo));
        ListView lv;
        lv = getListView();
        lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
        lv.setCacheColorHint(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        lv.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> timslist, View view,
                    int position, long id) {

                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), TimsListMore.class);

                i.putExtra("ct_number_pass", ct_number[position]);
                i.putExtra("ct_address_pass", ct_address[position]);
                i.putExtra("ct_phone_pass", ct_phone[position]);
                i.putExtra("ct_city_pass", ct_city[position]);
                i.putExtra("ct_province_pass", ct_province[position]);
                i.putExtra("ct_country_pass", ct_country[position]);
                i.putExtra("ct_pcode_pass", ct_pcode[position]);
                i.putExtra("ct_distance_pass", ct_distance[position]);

                startActivity(i);

            }
        });
    }

    protected boolean isKeyInstalled(Context context) {
          // the packagename of the 'key' app
          String proPackage = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";

          // get the package manager
          final PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();

          // get a list of installed packages
          List<PackageInfo> list = pm.getInstalledPackages(PackageManager.GET_DISABLED_COMPONENTS);

          // let's iterate through the list
          Iterator<PackageInfo> i = list.iterator();
          while(i.hasNext()) {
            PackageInfo p = i.next();
            // check if proPackage is in the list AND whether that package is signed
            //  with the same signature as THIS package
            if((p.packageName.equals(proPackage)) &&
               (pm.checkSignatures(context.getPackageName(), p.packageName) == PackageManager.SIGNATURE_MATCH))
              return true;
          }
          return false;
        }

    private void findCurrentLocation() {
        myLocation.getLocation(this, locationResult);
    }

    public LocationResult locationResult = new LocationResult() {


        public void gotLocation(Location location) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (location != null) {
                String infourl  = "http://www.somedomain.com/list.php?lat=" + location.getLatitude() + "&long=" + location.getLongitude();

            }
        }
    };
}
```

so this

```
String infourl  = "http://www.somedomain.com/list.php?lat=" + location.getLatitude() + "&long=" + location.getLongitude();
```

needs to go into

```
String result = null;
        InputStream is = null;
        StringBuilder sb = null;
        //http post
        try{
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("" + infourl + "");
            //httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            is = entity.getContent();
        }catch(Exception e){
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection"+e.toString());
        }
```

I would think this would not be a hard thing to do.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to try using a public string... hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Following on the previous question:

```
public LocationResult locationResult = new LocationResult() {
  String latitude = null;  
  String longitude = null;  

  public void gotLocation(Location location) {
    if (location != null) {
      latitude  = location.getLatitude() + "";
      longitude  = location.getLongitude() + "";
    }
  }

  public String getLatitude() {
    return latitude;
  }
  public String getLongitude() {
    return longitude;
  }
}
```

You would use it as

```
String location = new String (locationResult.getLatitude() + " " + locationResult.getLongitude());
```

anywhere in your Activity. Of course this is extremely rough and does not even check whether there is a valid location at all, but it gives you the idea to work around it.

Giving it a second thought, I believe what you really want is the opposite of what you're asking: if you need the lat and long values to send an http post, then I would do the post inside the `gotLocation` function. That way, you are sure that you won't send null values to the post. Create a method

```
public void postURL (String urlString) {
  if (urlString == null) return;
  HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(urlString);
  // whatever else code you have to handle responses, etc.
}
```

and call it from whithin the `gotLocation()` as

```
TimsList.this.postURL ("http://mytimmies.myfunhouse.net/app_main_list.php?lat=" + 
  location.getLatitude() + "&long=" + location.getLongitude());
```

Comment: This didn't seem to to much. also `public String getLatitude() {
    return latitude;
  }
  public String getLongitude() {
    return longitude;
  }` showed as unused by eclipse

Comment: Did you add the last line somewhere in your activity? That's how you use it.

Comment: this does not give the result i am trying to get. All i need to do is carry the lat and long from LocationResult and use it in the oncreate json url. Maybe i am not explaining it right i am still new to android. if i add `String Latitude = null; String Longitude = null;` before the `public void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {` it fixes my eclipse errors but passes Null so it is not adding the lat and long.

Comment: @Psycho I don't understand the problem here. The last line is an **example** of how to use it. Be my guest and write `json.put("latitude", locationResult.getLatitude());` instead.

Comment: I have added a updated java so you can see what i am talking about

Comment: I have try your suggestion and eclipse rewrites my code to fix errors. after i get all the errors gone so i can test the code and it FC the activity. errors are `(locationResult.getLatitude() + " " + locationResult.getLongitude()` the `getLatitude()` and `getLongitude()` eclipse adds `public String getLatitude() {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   return null;
  }` to my MyLocation.java

Comment: I dont understand why it is so hard to move simple info from the `public void gotLocation(Location location) {` to `public void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {`

Comment: You should not add those methods in there. Of course you'll get errors with them. Most probably you need to import MyLocation.LocationResult (if that's the structure of your classes). I can't tell where the error is without all the code, and that exceeds really the point of this question. Anyhow, I updated the answer with what I believe is a better approach.

Comment: I was playing with the idea of what you said and building the URL in the LocationResult and i am able to add the whole thing to a string infourl `public void gotLocation(Location location) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (location != null) {
             String infourl  = "http://mytimmies.myfunhouse.net/app_main_list.php?lat=" + location.getLatitude() + "&long=" + location.getLongitude();
                
            }
        }` How can i move that to replace the URL here `HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("infourl_should_Pass_To_Here");`

Comment: lol we were both editing our questions at the same time ill take a look and see what i can make of it and thx for the help your helping me learn lots.

Comment: @Psycho no, updating the string is trivial, but what you want to do is to send the post only when you get a location. That's the idea behind the code posted.

Comment: I have tried to modify the code with your postURL but I guess this is over my head i cant seem to tie things together correctly.

Comment: It seems my biggest issue i can don't understand how to use info outside the `public LocationResult` if i show the infourl string in a toast popup this shows the right info with the right Lat and long would it not be easy to access that string in the httppost in the oncreate area? If so how can i access that strings values?

Comment: It would be easy, but the string would not represent your location (it would be null instead). At this point, my best advise is to put this project on hold, and spend the weekend with a very small piece of code so you can play with it and understand it much better. See also the chapters on inner classes in the oracle tutorial. You can always come back to this project after you get those basic concepts.

Comment: BTW, this is the link to the Oracle docs: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/index.html

Comment: Thank you for your advice i will do a little more research on this.